# Flex HTTPService Timeout handler

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

my flex application sends a few concurent requests on startup. Sometimes it takes a lot of time to fetch them all so I've set them `requestTimeout` param to 5 secs. Additionally, I've defined a method that handles fault events. I'd like to resend a request when timeout occurs.
It doesn't work though. Could you take a look at the code?

```
protected function fatalErrorOccuredInfo(event:FaultEvent):void
{
    // get the operation
    var operation:mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation = mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation(event.target);

    operation.url += "?t=" + new Date().getTime();
    operation.useProxy = false;
    //this should resend a request that caused timeout
    operation.send();

}
```

I check whether a new request is sent in Network Monitor but it doesn't show anything :-(

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[WebService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html) class has a [getOperation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html#getOperation%28%29) function which returns an [AbstractOperation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/AbstractOperation.html).

Use it with `event.currentTarget.name`

So it would be something like

```
var operation:mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation = myWebService.getOperation(event.currentTarget.name);
operation.send();
```

I am pretty not sure but if `operation.send()` does not get to the result event, you might have to add an event listener for `ResultEvent.RESULT`

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I need it because operation is not null in this case so I have AbstractOperation filled with all data I need. Additionally, I don't get any error (null pointer or sth). It just don't send a request. You think that your solution will act differently?

Comment: Have you tried calling a different web service just for testing purposes? If `operation` is not null, then it should work. Did you put a breakpoint and see whether the the `operation.send()` is actually executed? :)

Comment: I haven't tried a different webservice but I have done some debugging and operation.send() is actually executed. I've even put Alert.show() in the next line and it always appears. Summarizing, it should work but it doesn't. Crap.

Comment: Have you tried finding out whether after `operation.send()` is called, whether the web service is actually invoked ?

Comment: No. How do I do that? All I know is that operation.service is null and should not be, I think. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: Well if the web service is a .NET Web Service,  you are in luck. You can start it in debug mode and put a break point and see if it gets hit. Anyway, did you try it the way I have specified? Is `operation.service` still null ?

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is with this line

```
operation.url += "?t=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Every time you make a request you append "?t=" + new Date().getTime();
Although that shouldn't be your main issue it is a problem.

```
private var operationURL:String = "someurl.com/page.php";
private function loadOperation( ):void{
  var operation:mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation = mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation(event.target);
  operation.url = operationURL + "?t=" + new Date().getTime();
  operation.useProxy = false;
  operation.send();
}

private var retryCount:int = 0
protected function fatalErrorOccuredInfo(event:FaultEvent):void{
  // don't want it stuck in an endless loading loop
  // 10 count is more then enough 
  if( retryCount < 10 ){
    this.loadOperation( );
    ++retryCount 
  }
}
```

Also, If you have FireFox installed get an add-on called HTTPfox.
HTTPfox will show you all requests made from the browser